# Simplify DAO Layer with Resteasy / Hibernate / Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao, resteasy

I'm looking for a cleaner code for my dao layer :

I have a generic dao interface :

```
public interface GenericDAO<T> {
    T save(T entity);
    T merge(T entity);
    void delete(T entity);
    T findFromId(int id);
    List<T> findAll();
}
```

An abstract implementation :

```
public abstract class AbstractGenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {
    [...]
}
```

For each database entity, I have two files :

An interface :

```
public interface UserDAO extends GenericDAO<UserPE> {  }
```

A concrete class :

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl extends AbstractGenericDAOImpl<UserPE> implements UserDAO {

    [ no code for most entities ]

}
```

I'm using spring injection like this :

```
@Autowired
private UserDAO userDao;
```

I'd like to use the generic dao for common entities, like :

```
@Autowired
private GenericDAO<MyEntity> myEntityDao;
```

But spring doesn't want to inject it (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException) and I don't know how to configure hibernate queries (which needs entity classes).

I'm using :
Spring 3.1.0
Hibernate 3.6.3
Resteasy 2.3.7

Do you have any idea ?

Thks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Spring 4, you will be able to use

```
@Autowired
private GenericDAO<MyEntity> myEntityDao;
```

if there is an implementation of GenericDAO without doing anything else.

Such capability was missing in Spring 3. 
Check out [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics) blog post for more details.

However, if you introduce Spring 4 to your project you might break the integration with RestEasy. That's something you'll need to check.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried to use spring 4 but I had problems with resteasy indeed. Do you know if there is a solution to integrate both ?

Comment: @NLAMY I have never actually tried to integrate Spring 4 with RestEasy. I have only used Spring 3.2 and RestEasy so I can't really help you out when it comes to that :(

Comment: I have to evaluate efforts needed for migrating from resteasy to spring web services. Don't know if I'll lose rest facilities.

Comment: @NLAMY It should be fairly easy to move to Spring MVC from RestEasy.